# How to prevent chafing in my lower regions

Tags: hiking, backpacking, preparation, injury

I'm training currently for a long distance walk (the [welsh 15 peaks in 24 hours](http://www.welsh3000s.co.uk/)) and I'm doing some long days (12 hours plus). I'm having some real trouble though with quite painful chafing in my (ahem) crotch area.

It appears to be being caused by my underwear and trousers rubbing while I'm sweating and moving.

I feel like I could do with some kind of Base Layer but not 100% sure what to do about this.

Anyone have any ideas how I can minimise this?

PS I'm not wearing a harness for this so it's not that that's causing problems

Comment: [This](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-hampshire-22485455) is not the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suffered from chaffing for years and tried a whole range of options. What I found that worked best is the Under Armour Original Boxer Jocks, the 9" version. They cover most of the thigh and holds well enough to keep everything separated to avoid the chaffing.

I get them from USA when they go on sale, but Wiggle, SportShoes and others stock them.

If a chaffing does start, keep a few wipes and some Fenistil Gel in hand to clean and treat the area. Chaffing happens when the skin is moist, irritated and has bacteria starting to grow. Wiping the area with the wipes and killing any bacteria with the Fenistil will make sure it won't get inflamed.

This combo of methods works for me for 24 hours speed hikes, multi days hikes (20-30 miles a day, 3+ days) and long trail runs.

Good luck with the Welsh 15.

Answer (score 7):

Having suffered similar on a marathon I had to run in freezing rain once (ending up with not just large areas with the skin chafed off entirely, but also deep cuts into my thigh muscles from the stitching!) I can heartily recommend combining very supportive underwear with non-slip, stretch leggings.

This way the only rubbing will be between the underwear and the leggings, and not between you and the fabric!

By personal preference, UnderArmor provide suitable items of clothing, but there are a wide range available.

(While recovering, Vaseline is your friend!)

Comment: Once I switched to well fitting, wicking boxer briefs, this problem mostly went away for me.

Answer (score 3):

As a runner, I use [Body Glide](https://www.bodyglide.com/) to prevent chafing.  It works like a charm.  Even if I put it on early (say, before driving to a race) it stays well enough to protect me.

It is a little on the pricey side, and I've read that you can get the same effect from [Aquaphor](http://discoveraquaphor.com/), so you may want to experiment.

Comment: I regularly use Bag Balm. It's super cheap and you can also use it on cows! As I understand it, these products start working against you when there's no opportunity to wash "down there" as they trap sweat/bacteria/gremlins (I'm not to sure of my science on this) and I've gotten pretty chafed on day 3. But for day hikes or short overnighters, it can't be beat.